# Injecting an ILog with MEF and a GuyWire

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, mef

While learning to crawl with DI tools, I am hoping someone can help me apply some concepts to a relatively simple scenario:

```
* Log4NetLogger : ILogger  
* DebugLogger : ILogger  
* NullLogger  : ILogger (no output: saves time & noise)
```

when my application is running, I want an ILog to be a Log4NetLogger, and when unit testing I want it to be either a DebugLogger or a NullLogger.

I have been looking at a [GuyWire](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/11/guywire.html) implementation [that I like](http://jfromaniello.blogspot.com/search?q=guywire), which uses WindsorInstallers. Not being biased towards any other DI tool and understanding the installer concept if not many of the nuances, Windsor seems as good as any other container.

So, would I have a ProductionLoggingInstaller that wires up Log4Net and a TestLoggingInstaller otherwise? How about switching tests to be either to DebugLogger or NullLogger?

And then there is MEF, which I get just enough at this point to think it can either solve this 'problem' also, but not sure if that would be without any container or in addition to the contain.

So how would you apply some combination of a GuyWire, Windsor, and or MEF to solve the logging resolution scenario here?

Cheers,
Berryl

NOTE: I am specifically using this logging scenario to apply some dependency injection tools (ie, MEF, Windsor, GuyWire, etc), as opposed to app.config of specific logging tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the different behavior from production and test by changing te *configuration* portion. Any well based logger should provide a comprensive suite of appenders ( even a null appender ) and leave the IoC responsible of choosing the engine, not how the engine itself is configured.

Comment: I really was mixing two things, one being the ability to 'eyeball' the output of unit testing artifacts, and the other actually being Logging of production code. I solved the first by just implementing some extensions in a Testing Support project. The other I am leaning towards a combination of Windor's LoggingFacility and a simplified interface over log4net - it will involve some appenders, so you get the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a Common Log (http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/docs/1.2.0/reference/html/logging.html).  It allows you to code to one interface and then change loggers via the config file.